# PHP shell_exec outputs question marks

Tags: php, bash, encoding, shell-exec

I'm using a PHP script that calls external program via `shell_exec` and I'm interested in it's output. The problem is that output always comes as question marks when I use russian letters.

The whole thing is runnnig on Ubuntu 11.10, when external program executed in bash it yields correct output (no question marks).

Here's the code that I have:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
echo morpher("Антон");

function morpher($command) {
    static $path = '/usr/bin/mono %sengine/helpers/language/morpher.exe %s';
    $path = sprintf($path, SITE_ROOT, $command);

    $output = shell_exec($path);

    error_log($output) // series of question marks instead of russian letters
    error_log( mb_detect_encoding($output) ); // outputs ASCII
    error_log( iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', $output) ); // same question marks

    return explode("\n", $output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `LANG="en_US.UTF8"` like so: `'LANG="en_US.UTF8" mono %sengine/helpers/language/morpher.exe %s';`